# Let $\displaystyle f$ be differentiable, $\displaystyle f(x)=0$ for $|x| \geq 10 $ and $g(x)=\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z}f(x+k).$

Tags: real-analysis

I came across the following problem that says:

> Let $\displaystyle f \colon \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be differentiable function and $\displaystyle f(x)=0$ for $|x| \geq 10.$ Let  $g(x)=\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z}f(x+k).$ Then   which of the following is true?
>   $1.g$ is differentiable and $g'$ has infinitely many zeros
>   $2.g$ is continuous and $g'$ has no zeros
>   $3.g$ is differentiable and $g'$ has no zeros
>   $4.g$ is differentiable and $g'$ has only finitely many zeros.

I am not sure about how to progress with it.Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Try to see what $g^\prime (x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}f(x+20k)$ looks like, in terms of $f$. And use it to construct $g$. This will help you get a better picture.

Comment: In a test : f=0 is possible so (1)..

Answer (score 4):

**Differentiability:** for sure $g$ is differentiable as this sum is locally finite and each $x\longmapsto f(x+k)$ is differentiable. Fix $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then observe
$$
x>n-1\;\mbox{and}\; k\geq 11-n\quad\Rightarrow \quad x+k>n-1+11-n=10\quad\Rightarrow \quad f(x+k)=0
$$
and 
$$
x<n+1\;\mbox{and}\; k\leq -11-n\quad\Rightarrow \quad x+k<n+1-11-n=-10\quad\Rightarrow \quad f(x+k)=0.
$$
So if $x$ belongs to $(n-1,n+1)$, the terms $f(x+k)$ vanish for all $k\geq 11-n$ and $k\leq -11-n$. Thus
$$
g(x)=\sum_{k=-10-n}^{10-n}f(x+k)\qquad\forall x\in (n-1,n+1).
$$
First, this shows that $g$ is well-defined. And since this is a finite sum of differentiable functions on $(n-1,n+1)$, $g$ is differentiable on $(n-1,n+1)$ and, simply,
$$
g'(x)=\sum_{k=-10-n}^{10-n}f'(x+k)\qquad\forall x\in (n-1,n+1).
$$
Now $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(n-1,n+1)$. Hence $g$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

**Note:** observe that $g$ is $1$-periodic as the index set $\mathbb{Z}$ is invariant under the shift $x\longmapsto x+1$. So it suffices to prove the differentiability of $g$ on $(0,2)$. But it does not really simplify the argument.

**Zeros of the derivative:**  by periodicity, as soon as $g'$ has a zero $x_0$, it must have infinitely many zeros as it vanishes on $x_0+\mathbb{Z}$. Now since $g$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and $1$-periodic, it suffices to apply Rolle on the interval $[0,1]$, as $g(0)=g(1)$, to see that there exists $x_0\in (0,1)$ such that $g'(x_0)=0$.

**Conclusion:** 1 is the only correct option.

Comment: I could not understand the line "If $x$ belongs to $(n-1,n+1)$, then $x+k>10$ for all $k\geq 11-n$"..Can you clarify a bit? We know that $f(x)=0$ for $|x| \geq 10$. From this ,how can we deduce the aforementioned line.

Comment: @learner Is is better like that?

Comment: Thanks a lot @julien. It is clear now.

Comment: @learner Youu're welcome. Is the rest of the argument clear enough for you?

Comment: The rest of the argument seems fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try it with $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, what is $g(x)$ and $g'(x)$ than?

If you don't want to cheat use that $g(x)=g(x+1)$ for all $x$.

Comment: I think (using your hints) that option $(1)$ will be the right choice.But not sure why the condition $|x| \geq 10$ has been given in the problem.

Comment: if it's not given, $g(x)$ is not well defined in general. They used it to make the infinite sum to a finite one by making nearly all terms zero

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_0 \in \Bbb R$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Put $a = \lfloor x_0 - \epsilon \rfloor$ and $b = \lceil x_0 + \epsilon \rceil$. We have:
$$
\forall x \in (x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon), \forall k \in \Bbb Z : \begin{cases}
k > 10 - a & \implies x + k > a + 10 - a = 10\\
k < -10 - b & \implies x + k < b -10 - b = -10
\end{cases}
$$

Hence, $g(x)$ is locally the sum of a finite number of shifts of $f$:

$$
\forall x \in (x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon) : g(x) = \sum_{k=-10-b}^{10-a} f(x + k)
$$

Since the sum is finite and each $f(x + k)$ is differentiable, it follows that $g$ is differentiable at $x_0$. Since $x_0$ is arbitrary, it follows that $g$ is differentiable everywhere.

$g$ is a periodic function because:
$$
g(x + 1) = \sum_{k \in \Bbb Z} f(x + k + 1) = \sum_{k' \in \Bbb Z} f(x + k') = g(x)
$$
(where $k' = k + 1$)

By [Rolle's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) applied to $[a, a+1]$ for any $a \in \Bbb R$, $g'$ has a zero in $(a, a+1)$. Since $a$ is arbitrary, $g'$ has infinitely many zeros.

Comment: I was too slow typing. If I had seen it before, I would have simply upvoted your answer. So I do it now, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Put $10=:N$ and let an $R\geq1$ be given. When $|x|<R$ and $|k|>N+R$ then $$|x+k|\geq |k|-|x|>N+R-R=N\ .$$
It follows that
$$f(x+k)=0 \quad\bigl(|k|>N+R)\ ,$$
so that for such $x$ we have
$$g(x)=\sum_{k=-N-R}^{N+R} f(x+k)\ .\tag{1}$$
Since we now have a finite sum the value $g(x)$ is well defined; furthermore it easy to see that replacing $R$ by an $R'>R$ does not change the value of $g(x)$. As $R$ can be arbitrarily large it follows that $g$ is well defined and differentiable on all of ${\mathbb R}$.

When $|x|<R$ and $|x+1|<R$ we may use $(1)$ to compute both $g(x)$ and $g(x+1)$, and we obtain
$$\eqalign{g(x+1)-g(x)&=\sum_{k=-N-R}^{N+R} f(x+1+k)-\sum_{k=-N-R}^{N+R} f(x+k) \cr 
&=\sum_{k'=-N-R+1}^{N+R+1} f(x+k')-\sum_{k=-N-R}^{N+R} f(x+k)\cr 
&=f\bigl((x+1)+N+R\bigr)-f(x-N-R)\cr 
&=0\ .\cr}$$
It follows that $g:\ {\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ is periodic with period $1$. Since $g$ is continuous it takes at least one $\max$ and one $\min$ per period, and this assures an infinity of zeros for $g'$.

It follows that (i) is true, and that the other proposed statements are false.